# Python Delete Duplicates From Loop Output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json
import requests
import re

tag = "tag=mirai"
hd = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
r = requests.post ('https://urlhaus-api.abuse.ch/v1/tag/', data=tag, headers=hd)
c = ['urls', 'url']
data = json.loads (r.text)

for i in range (0, 998):
    fff = data['urls'][i]['url']
    pattern = r"((([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))"
    ips = [match[0] for match in re.findall (pattern, fff)]
    list2 = []
    for item in ips:
        if item != []:
            list2.append (item)
            print(list2)
```

I wrote this code and output type list of lines I searching for 5 days
throughout and any finds answer of problem.

Example output

```
['51.15.64.60']
['51.15.64.60']
['149.3.170.181']
['149.3.170.181']
['89.248.166.183']
['185.132.53.30']
['185.132.53.30']
['185.132.53.30']
```

Necessary output

```
['51.15.64.60']
['149.3.170.181']
['89.248.166.183']
['185.132.53.30']
```

Comment: Read about [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm interested to know what you searched for five days that you couldn't find a good solution -- sometimes knowing what to look for is half the battle. For example, what you really want to do here is to remove duplicates from the _list_ in which you store the IP addresses, not from _loop output_.

Comment: I tried set() but no effect 

{'51.15.64.60'}
{'51.15.64.60'}
{'149.3.170.181'}
{'149.3.170.181'}
{'89.248.166.183'}
{'185.132.53.30'}
{'185.132.53.30'}
{'185.132.53.30'}
{'45.13.58.4'}
{'89.34.27.168'}
{'89.34.27.168'}
{'89.34.27.168'}

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the `item` (list) is not already in `list2` before adding it.

This answer assumes that you want the `list2` to have no duplicate objects but to keep the order of insertion.

(If what you want is for `list2` to have no *sequential* duplicate objects, or if the order of insertion is unimportant, there would be different answers.)

```
...
if item != []:
   if item not in list2: # Add this line
     list2.append (item)
     print(list2)
```

Comment: I want to get unique lines in output

Comment: The answer here will give you unique lines. Just put that if line before the append line.

Comment: I add but same result

Comment: ['51.15.64.60']
['51.15.64.60']
['149.3.170.181']
['149.3.170.181']
['89.248.166.183']
['185.132.53.30']
['185.132.53.30']
['185.132.53.30']
['45.13.58.4']
['89.34.27.168']
['89.34.27.168']
['89.34.27.168']
['45.13.58.4']
['45.13.58.4']

Answer (score 1):

Use if statement to see if item already exist in list2 or not

Below is what should work for you..

```
import json
import requests
import re

tag = "tag=mirai"
hd = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
r = requests.post ('https://urlhaus-api.abuse.ch/v1/tag/', data=tag, headers=hd)
c = ['urls', 'url']
data = json.loads (r.text)

for i in range (0, 998):
    fff = data['urls'][i]['url']
    pattern = r"((([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))"
    pattern2 = r"^(\S++).*\R(?=(?>.*\R)*?\1 )"
    ips = [match[0] for match in re.findall (pattern, fff)]
    list2 = []
    for item in ips:
        if item != []:
            if item not in list2:
                list2.append (item)
                print(list2)
```

Comment: list2 statement required for removing empty lines